# Signing data with smartcards on Mac in C++

Tags: c++, macos, cryptography, smartcard

is there any support in Mac OS X for signing data using smartcards? I have looked through the system headers and found only vauge references to smart card support (in SecKeychain.h), which didn't really take me anywhere.

If there's no built-in support, which are my options (ie. what free/non-free libraries exist that can help me)?

Comment: Retagged "smartcards" to the more common "smartcard" tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, for reference.
The [OpenSC](http://www.opensc-project.org/) libraries provides everything you need to deal with smartcards, and it is cross-platform (Windows, Linux and Mac), and its license is good for commercial projects.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple-CDSA mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/apple-cdsa) is probably the best place to ask this; CDSA stands for Common Data Security Architecture, which includes all of the security/keychain/signing infrastructure on Mac OS X, including any support for smart-card security.

Plenty of people who use and work on CDSA will be there.  It will probably also be worth checking the archives; someone may have already done what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The [MUSCLE](http://linuxnet.com) stuff also provides an API, PKCS#11 module, etc., and works on OS X.

The MUSCLE Framework and OpenSC may support different cards so it depends on what kind you are using.